# launching Jython console with Tomcat 8 servlet

Tags: java, python, jython-2.7

If I launch Jython like this:

```
"java -cp jython.jar" 
or
"java -cp jython.jar org.python.util.jython"
```

works ok and launches Jython REPL

if I include another jar like:

```
"java -cp jython.jar:servlet-api.jar org.python.util.jython"
```

gaves me the folowing error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.python.util.jython

Any ideas how can I fix the error?

(both .jar(s) are available and in the current folder)

Answer (score 0):

`java -cp jython.jar:servlet-api.jar org.python.util.jython` works for me on OpenJDK 7u221 and Jython 2.7.1.